# How can I install the grunt-cli without getting errors?

Tags: node.js, bash, gruntjs

Inspired by Chris Coyier's [post](http://24ways.org/2013/grunt-is-not-weird-and-hard/), I decided I'd give grunt a go. But I'm having big problems getting set up.

First, I installed Node.

Then I added a package.json file to my project root, including this:

```
{
  "name": "example-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1"
  }
}
```

Then I ran `npm install`

Finally, I ran `npm install -g grunt-cli`

which came back with a ton of errors:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23',
npm ERR!      '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53',
npm ERR!      'Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 11.4.2
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "grunt-cli"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/bryce/repo
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.23
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.17
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli
npm ERR! fstream_type Directory
npm ERR! fstream_class DirWriter
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli'
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/bryce/repo/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
Bryce:repo bryce$ npm install -g grunt-cli
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23',
npm ERR!      '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53',
npm ERR!      'Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 11.4.2
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "grunt-cli"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/bryce/repo
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.23
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.17
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli
npm ERR! fstream_type Directory
npm ERR! fstream_class DirWriter
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli'
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/bryce/repo/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I assume the above errors are the reason that when I tried to run `grunt`, I simply get `-bash: grunt: command not found`

Anyone out there know what's happening?

Comment: Have you tried with sudo? Also this is a possible duplicate for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736943/sudo-npm-install-g-grunt-cli-gives-me-an-error

Comment: you were right. I don't know how I didn't see that in my googling. Thank you so much!

Comment: the problem in the question you referenced is a little different, since the asker was using sudo too, but the answer was exactly what I needed. What's the proper stack overflow protocol when that happens? delete the question? answer my own?

Comment: @BryceJohnson How did you install node on OSX?

Comment: Answering the question is always a good thing. Deleting is reserved for unrelated or incorrect questions.

Comment: @jibsales Use Brew for installing node and other packages on OSX

Comment: @Hugo I know, I was asking the OP how THEY installed. The need to use sudo indicates they didn't use brew

Comment: @jibsales Sorry my bad.

Comment: @jibsales i just got it from nodejs.org and installed it directly. not through the terminal. Thanks for the tip... i'll look into this Brew thingy.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All it took was adding 'sudo', since I didn't have permission to install the grunt-cli by default. Once I ran the following command and entered my password, it worked as expected.

```
sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: npm shouldn't be run with sudo

Comment: @l19 installing anything with sudo will changes the user. Apparently sudo npm uses the "nobody" user. However any other program you run will run as your user. If there are permission differences between "nobody" and your user this could cause problems.

This also implies the "nobody" can somehow do something that you can't, which has even scarier security implications... But is neither here nor there.

Comment: `sudo npm` recently broke servers setting incorrect access rights. `npm` must not (i.e. officially, by documentation) be run with increased privileges.

Answer (score 9):

EDIT:
The article quoted below is quite old and refers to pre-v0.3 **Yikes!** Currently, if `npm` is run with `sudo` rights it will downgrade to the nobody user before executing commands.

According to the maintainer of `npm`, installing packages with `sudo` is considered bad practice because you are allowing that package to have complete control of your system and you can't and SHOULDN'T trust these packages with root access.

http://howtonode.org/introduction-to-npm

Comment: Note: Installing as root (with `sudo`) has been [recommended since NPM 0.3](https://github.com/npm/npm#permissions-when-using-npm-to-install-other-stuff) ([Feb 2011](https://github.com/npm/npm/tree/v0.3.0)). It will run them as the "nobody" user. Most information to the contrary came from the combined year of 0.1 and 0.2 before that.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski - I discovered that information after this post as well. In the end, I still maintain that not using `sudo` is better if it can be avoided. Especially on OSX.

Answer (score 1):

Since you should not install using sudo - you will do this before installing packages and no longer will hit permission errors:

sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local

source: https://howtonode.org/introduction-to-npm

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend installing grunt within your project (instead of using the -g option).

For example, to install the Grunt command line tools use:

```
cd ~/path-to-my-project
npm install grunt-cli --save-dev
```

If you want to run grunt then you use:

```
cd ~/path-to-my-project
./node_modules/./bin/grunt
```

By installing grunt-cli within your project, you'll have full control over which version gets installed and you don't have to rely on inconsistent PATH variables.

Comment: not sure why but for me the binary is at `./node_modules/.bin/grunt` not ./bin.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue as well, and after reading through the output a little closer i realized that my installed version of node.js was not compatible with the current version of grunt-cli.

Updated node.js problem solved.